# How to create super user in MariaDB MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux

I have MyCloudMirror NAS box and I accidentally delete root user from MySQL now I can't login to mysql.

I have uninstall and reinstall the phpmyadmin app but that did not make any different

I also try following but nothing is working

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

below command show that all permission are assign

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

this doesnt assign all permission the trigger are uncheck

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

If I try to check triger from myphpadmin and click on apply i get error message

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  *.* TO 'root'@'%' REQUIRE NONE WITH GRANT
> OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0
> MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0; MySQL said:
> Documentation
>
> #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` is not enough.

On MySQL 8+ you must execute the next statements:

```sql
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, 
      FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, 
      CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, 
      REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, 
      CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE TABLESPACE, CREATE ROLE, DROP ROLE 
ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT APPLICATION_PASSWORD_ADMIN,AUDIT_ABORT_EXEMPT,AUDIT_ADMIN,
      AUTHENTICATION_POLICY_ADMIN,BACKUP_ADMIN,BINLOG_ADMIN,BINLOG_ENCRYPTION_ADMIN,
      CLONE_ADMIN,CONNECTION_ADMIN,ENCRYPTION_KEY_ADMIN,FLUSH_OPTIMIZER_COSTS,
      FLUSH_STATUS,FLUSH_TABLES,FLUSH_USER_RESOURCES,GROUP_REPLICATION_ADMIN,
      INNODB_REDO_LOG_ARCHIVE,INNODB_REDO_LOG_ENABLE,PASSWORDLESS_USER_ADMIN,
      PERSIST_RO_VARIABLES_ADMIN,REPLICATION_APPLIER,REPLICATION_SLAVE_ADMIN,
      RESOURCE_GROUP_ADMIN,RESOURCE_GROUP_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,
      SERVICE_CONNECTION_ADMIN,SET_USER_ID,SHOW_ROUTINE,SYSTEM_USER,
      SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN,TABLE_ENCRYPTION_ADMIN,XA_RECOVER_ADMIN 
ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT PROXY ON ``@`` TO `root`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: What is full process of creating new user without knowing username and password. I do have full access to putty for NAS

Comment: @maj See [How to Reset the Root Password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html), "Generic Instructions" (the operations must be performed locally, not remotely, via CLI). Instead of setting new password to existing account you create new account, flush privileges, set grants with the above statements and flush again, then restart server and check.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed the issue

Run /usr/bin/mysql_reset.py --reset

The above command reset all settings on DB